# Print an entire Facebook chat/message conversation thread

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to set up printing an entire Facebook thread?

Using the print dialog, it seems to only grab with is available up to "Loading earlier messages" If one has 5000+ messages in one thread this can be a pain.

Is there a way to print or export this for easy reading?

Comment: Have to use the API to make a custom app for this. No other way.

Comment: Or use firefox with this [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/facebook-chat-history-manager/?src=search).

Comment: The firefox extension is a possible answer

Comment: Try it and let me know. Will add it as answer then. :)

Comment: Tried it, but I will have to actually populate it with messages because it only retrieves messages after the add-on is installed looks pretty neat though.

Comment: The messages should all be present in the Download Your Information tool on Facebook, right? you could try that and see if it's easily printable

Comment: @Igy You are right. I didn't think about that, waiting for the archive to be generated now

Comment: It takes a while from what i remember, but the zip file for me had a HTML file with each friend's conversations

Comment: @Igy cool, well that sounds like a possible answer as long it's easily printable. If it is bundled in HTML I could change around the CSS to suit. Thanks, you could post that as answer or I could when I try it out, doesn't matter to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably get the information you need from Facebook's 'Download your information' tool - this is accessed from the Account Settings page, via a link marked 'Download a copy of your Facebook data'

It takes a while, but the archive will include chat messages

[image: Tool screenshot]

Comment: This works for the text, but all pictures are missing.

Comment: Doesn't work with people you're not friends with anymore :(

Comment: Also some smileys won't make it.

Answer (score 3):

I ran this small script in the developer console of the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to download a full conversation as JSON:

```
var messages = [];
var messageId = 123456; //etc
var token = $('#access_token').val();

function process(data) {
    if(data.data.length) {
        messages = messages.concat(data.data)
    }
    if(data.paging && data.paging.next) {
        console.log('Getting next page');
        return $.getJSON(data.paging.next).then(process)
    }
}

$.getJSON(
     'https://graph.facebook.com/' + messageId + '/comments' +
     '?format=json&access_token=' + token
).then(process).then(function() {
    var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(messages)], {type: 'text/json'});
    location.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
})
```

You'll need to paste `jquery.min.js` in there, and give yourself a `read_mailbox` extended permission, before running that

Answer (score 0):

You can first save your chat with the help of a browser extension called Messages Saver for Facebook. Download and install it from [here](https://chatsaver.org/files.html)

It can save your chats in various formats:

- plain text
- HTML with all the media in a chat
- CSV file for easy export to Excel
- ZIP archive, then all the media of a chat are saved locally to your computer, which makes your chat virtually independent from Facebook servers.

After having saved your chat you can open it in your browser and press CTRL+P which will take you to a print-out window.

Hope that helps.