# How to download a conversation in Facebook

Tags: facebook-messenger

I need your help to download the whole- complete conversation with my friend in Facebook. The way I can do that is to scroll (∞) and copy, but that will take more than an hour or a day. Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either use [THIS FIREFOX Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/facebook-chat-history-manager/?src=search)
OR
You can download all of your facebook data via facebook itself!

Here's a quote from the facebook help button>search: "download"
 **How can I download my information on Facebook.**

> You can download your information from the Account Settings page.
>
> 1. Click  at the top right of any Facebook page and select Account Settings
> 2. Click General in the left-hand column
> 3. Click on "Download a copy of your Facebook data"
> 4. Click Start My Archive
>
>    Because this download contains your timeline information, you should
>      keep it secure and be careful when storing, sending or uploading it to
>      any other services. Learn more about what info is included in your
>      download. If you don't have a Facebook account, you can request the
>      removal of your data.
>      https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=212802592074644#How-can-I-download-my-information-from-Facebook?

**When I download my infomation from facebook, what is included in the
 file?**

> When you download your information your file will include:
>
> - Your timeline information (ex: your contact information, interests, groups)
> - Content that you and your friends have posted to your timeline
> - Photos and videos that you have uploaded to your account
> - Your friend list
> - Notes you have created
> - Events to which you have RSVP’d
> - Your sent and received messages
> - Any comments that you and your friends have made on your timeline posts, photos, and other timeline content
> - Note that we store different types of data for different time periods, so we may not have all of your data since you joined
>     Facebook.
> - Learn more about the different ways to access your Facebook info.
>
> https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=202639089780201#When-I-download-my-information-from-Facebook,-what-is-included-in-the-file?

Hope this helps. The downloading of your content from facebook might take some time, but it's a one click way to download it, and not loads of scrolling on the chat page...

EDIT:
Also, **in Chrome**, you can do this (just checked and is this method is functioning properly):

In Google Chrome, open your chat/message of your conversation with your Friend and

1. **right click** on the conversation > **Inspect Element**.
2. Look for the following **DIV code** in the html source of the page:

   ul class="uiList -cx-PRIVATE-webMessengerReadView__messagelist -cx-PRIVATE-uiList__vert" id="webMessengerRecentMessages" role="log"
3. When found, **right click** on it > **Copy as HTML**.
4. **Save this html** code copied in your clipboard, **to a blank html** document.
5. **That's it**, you can print edit or do anything with your copied chat conversation..!

sources:

- [Facebook - download chat history](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33171/facebook-download-chat-history)
- [Print an entire Facebook chat/message conversation thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25393/print-an-entire-facebook-chat-message-conversation-thread)

[image]

Comment: @user2377276 I liked more the second method by expecting the element. But after doing the same steps i got only today's messages but not all for 1 year. :(

Comment: @user2377276 Both solutions did not work for me. The extension did not work, and the second method only allowed me to download a part of the conversation.

Comment: I did not find either solution to work, but I found [these Python scripts](https://github.com/RaghavSood/FBMessageScraper) to work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.facebook.com/help/212802592074644?sr=11&query=download&sid=0kMFOrIVqle4NfFGS:

[image: FB download help]

- Go to settings (eg click on the globe at the top right of your FB
  home screen and then on the right-hand item `Settings` at the top of
  the dropdown):

[image: FB Settings]

- Click on `General` at the top left (gears icon):

[image: FB General and Download]

- Click on “Download a copy of your Facebook data.” (below “General
  Account Settings”).
- Click on “Start My Archive” ("Download Archive" if you have done this
  before.)

[image: FB Download Archive]

- Re-enter your password and click “Submit”.

As this could take a while (in my case only seconds) you will receive an e-mail when the download is ready:

[image: FB notification mail]

The download is a .zip file containing several folders and in folder html there is a file `messages.htm`.

Comment: The data is incomplete, tough: Images posted during a conversation are missing.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this Python script](https://github.com/RaghavSood/FBMessageScraper) to work perfectly to scrape the contents of just one conversation. It saves it as a .json file though, so you'd have to write something to parse it properly (or just view the plain text).

Comment: I have fixed and extended the scripts in [this Python project of mine](http://github.com/5agado/conversation-analyzer).
In particular check for the _conversationScraper.py_ file in the _util_ folder. You can simply download all the messages for a specific conversation by specifying the corresponding conversation ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a browser extension called Messages Saver for Facebook. 
Download and install it from here [Messages Saver for Facebook](https://chatsaver.org/files.html)

It can save your chats in various formats:

- plain text
- HTML with all the media in a chat
- CSV file for easy export to Excel
- ZIP archive, then all the media of a chat are saved locally to your computer, which makes your chat virtually independent from Facebook servers.

Hope that helps.